# Android SQLiteDatabase doesn't seem to update

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm relatively new at SQLite and Android.

But everytime I count entries from this updated table, it returns zero.

Relevant pices of code:

(1)

```
    final DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
```

(2)

```
    SQLiteDatabase setter = db.getWritableDatabase();
    setter.beginTransaction();



            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("_id", 1);
            values.put("Date", date);
            values.put("Example", "example");
```

etc...

```
            setter.insert("Name_Of_Table", "_id", values);


            setter.endTransaction();

            Cursor cursor;

            setter.beginTransaction();
            cursor = setter.rawQuery("Select Count (*) From Name_Of_Table", null);
            setter.endTransaction();

            int integer;

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            integer = cursor.getInt(0);
                setter.close();
                db.close();

            cursor.close();
```

Does this mean that my DB does not get updated as I think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` before ending your transaction to commit your changes. Otherwise the changes get rolled back.